# Start Docker Daemon as other user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, daemons

Guys, I need to start docker daemon as other user under my Ubuntu 14.04..
I have this user in the sudoers' group and in the docker's group, but, what I need is the docker daemon running as my "test" user.

**test@test:/usr/bin$ start docker**

start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.88" (uid=1100 pid=24071 comm="start docker ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init ")

What can I do to run docker daemon under my 'test' user without sudo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, Docker requires root privileges to run. The techniques to isolate the process, mount file systems, configure a private network stack, etc, cannot be performed without root privileges.